# Add tag after each li text

Tags: jquery

I need to add a `<span>` tag after the text of each `<li>`, not before the closing `</li>`!

```
<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b
      <ol>
        <li>c</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li>d</li>
</ol>
```

expected

```
<ol>
  <li>a<span></span></li>
  <li>b<span></span>
      <ol>
        <li>c<span></span></li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li>d<span></span></li>
</ol>
```

My attempt

```
    $('li').each(function() {
    var txtu = $(this).text();
    var htmlu = $(this).html().replace('' + txtu + '', txtu + '<span></span>');
    $(this).html(htmlu);
})
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Comment: $('li').each(function() {var txtu=$(this).text(); var htmlu=$(this).html().replace(''+txtu+'', txtu+'<span></span>');  $(this).html(htmlu);})

Comment: @degeaba Include your code in the post, using the "Edit" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try This Code:-

```
jQuery('ol li').each(function() {
    if($(this).has('ol').length > 0){
        $(this).children('ol').before('<span></span>');
    }else{
        $(this).append('<span></span>') ;   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `each` loop to get this done.

```js
$('ol li').each(function() {
    if($(this).has('ol').length > 0){
        $(this).children('ol').before('<span></span>');
    }else{
        $(this).append('<span></span>') ;   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b
      <ol>
        <li>c</li>
      </ol>
  </li>
  <li>d</li>
</ol>
```

Use developer tool bar to check, now there is a `span` tag before `li` closing